# Getting "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gnutls_free" when using GnuTLS 3.1.6 from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, gnutls

I am attempting to build a project in Visual Studio 2012 that uses GnuTLS. I downloaded the latest official Windows build from [the website](http://www.gnutls.org/download.html), and created a link library by running `lib /def:libgnutls-28.def` in the bin directory form a Visual Studio command prompt.

After adding a `typedef long ssize_t`, the code compiles fine, but linking fails with the following error:

```
source_file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gnutls_free
C:\Path\to\executable.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I am calling `gnutls_free` to free some memory allocated and returned by the library. If I remove the call to `gnutls_free`, the project links successfully. Given that `gnutls_free` is just a global variable (containing a function pointer) exported by the library, I'm not sure why accessing it results in an unresolved reference to a different symbol. I have verified that `gnutls_free` is not `#define`ed to anything.

As a test, I tried doing `gnutls_free_function test = gnutls_free;` which also resulting in the link error. Running `grep -w -r _gnutls_free .` on the GnuTLS source code returns nothing, so I am at a loss.

Any ideas for getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Adding `__declspec(dllimport)` to the declaration of `gnutls_free` in `gnutls.h` allows the link to succeed. Is there any way to accomplish this without maintaining a custom version of the header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to have the linker or import library automatically dereference the IAT's pointer to the data item the same way that is done for functions (via a small trampoline function that is statically linked into the module importing the function).  The `__declspec(dllimport)` attribute tells that compiler that this dereferencing needs to be done so it can insert code to perform the dereferencing of the IAT pointer implicitly. This allows exported data to be accessed and for functions allows the compiler to call the imported function via an indirect call through the IAT pointer rather than by calling the trampoline function.

See a couple of Raymond Chen's articles about `dllimport` for a good explanation of what goes on for function calls (he didn't discuss importing data, unfortunately):

- [Calling an imported function, the naive way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/21/673830.aspx)
- [How a less naive compiler calls an imported function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/24/676669.aspx)

The MS linker or import library doesn't have a mechanism to help the compiler get imported data in a 'naive' way - the compiler needs the the `__delcspec(dllimport)` hint that an extra dereference through the IAT is needed. Anyway, the point of all this is that it seems there's no way to import data except by using the `__declspec(dllimport)` attribute.

If you want to avoid modifying the `gnutls` distribution (which I can understand), here's one rather imperfect workaround:

You can create a small object file that contains nothing but a simple wrapper for `gnutls_free()`; since `gnutls_free()` has an interface with no real dependencies, you can have the necessary declarations 'hardcoded' instead of including `gnutls.h`:

```
typedef void (*gnutls_free_function) (void *);
__declspec(dllimport) extern gnutls_free_function gnutls_free;

void xgnutls_free(void* p)
{
    gnutls_free(p);
}
```

Have your code call `xgnutls_free()` instead of `gnutls_free()`.

Not a great solution - it requires your code to call a wrapper (so it's particularly not great if you'll be incorporating 3rd party code that might depend on `gnutls_free()`), but it might be good enough.

Comment: Very informative, thanks. Is there anyway to mark all of the declarations in a header file as `__declspec(dllimport)` without modifying each and every declaration? (I suppose you probably would have mentioned it if there were.)

Comment: @rkjnsn: not that I'm aware of.  Also, if you plan to add the `declspec` to the header, use a macro (like `#define GNUTLS_DLLAPI __declspec(dllimport)`) so that if you ever find yourself in a situation where you need to build the DLL you can easily change it to `_declspec(dllexport)` for that build.